# Run event on hovering on drawn line on canvas in python's tkinter gui

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Is there any way to have an event for hovering/clicking on a drawn line on the Canvas widget (not the widget itself)?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a tag on the line and then bind Enter or Button-1 to the tag with the tag_bind method of the canvas widget.

Comment: you don't have to add a tag, you can bind directly to the item.

Comment: Right, you can always use the id instead of the tag.  I forgot that.  The tag is advantageous if you want to bind a number of canvas items to the same event.